# How to let screen detach immediately after the job starts running (before finishing)?

Tags: gnu-screen

I usually start a long-haul job with `screen`, and once the job starts, I just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>d</kbd> to detach.

How to achieve the same thing using command line?

I tried

```
screen -dm bash -c 'mySlowJob.sh > /dev/null'
```

but the screen doesn't detach until the job is done.

Comment: Hmmm... This does what it's supposed to do on my end. Do you have anything that may interfere in your `~/.screenrc` file or in the Bash startup scripts?

Comment: You can use 'nohup'.

Comment: @rajaganesh87: `nohup`, by itself, is not close to being a solution or even a helpful suggestion. How do you suggest that the OP use `nohup` to get his command to work?